# $p$-adic polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: polynomials, p-adic-number-theory

If $f(X) = \sum_{k=0}^d a_kX^k\in \mathbb{Q}_p[X]$, does the condition that 
$$|f(x)|_p < 1\;\text{for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$}$$
guarantee that $f(X)\in\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$?

The converse is obviously true by the strong triangle inequality, but I am not sure how to approach this direction since the triangle inequality gives no information about the coefficients of $f(X)$ afaik. I tried applying Hensel's lemma, but all I know is $|f'(x)|_p \leq \max_{1\leq k\leq d}\{|k|_p|a_k|_p|x|_p^{k-1}\}$ and if $|a_1|<1$, then this is $\leq 1/p$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Let us consider $f=(x-0)(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-(p-1))$. Now let $a$ be an element in $\Bbb Z_p$. Take it modulo $p$, getting $a_0$, lift this to $0,1,2,\dots,(p-1)$. So for at least one of the factors, for $(x-a_0)$ we have $|a-a_0|_p<1$. The others are in $p$-norm all $\le 1$.

Comment: The result doesn't hold in $\Bbb{Q}_p$ (because the residue field is finite) but it does in $\bigcup_{p \nmid n}\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n)$ or any extension whose residue field is infinite. @dan_fulea's example is $f(X) = \frac{X^p-X}{p}$.

Comment: @reuns I understand the counterexample dan_fulea wrote, but I can't make heads or tails of your comment. Could you expand on why the residue field being finite is an obstruction to the proposition I wrote and why it does hold in local fields with infinite residue field? Perhaps a proof sketch if you know one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R$ be a DVR with maximal ideal $(\pi)$.

- If $R/(\pi)$ is a finite field with $q$ elements then $f = \frac{X^q-X}{\pi}\in Frac(R)[X]$ is not in $R[X]$ but $f(R) \subset R$.
- Otherwise $R/(\pi)$ is not a finite field. Let $f\in R[X]$ such that $f(R) \subset \pi R$. 
  Its reduction $\overline{f} \in R/(\pi)[X]$ vanishes for all $a \in R/(\pi)$, it has infinitely many roots, thus $\overline{f} = 0 \bmod \pi$ and $f \in \pi R[X]$. Whence for $g \in Frac(R)[X]$ then $g(R) \subset R$ iff $g \in R[X]$.